# Linux CMake build dynamic library without linking depedencies

Tags: linux, cmake, openssl, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm coding a C++ library on Linux, the lib name is libic. libic use openssl. When I build libic on host Ubuntu 18.04, no error occurs. But when I cross-compile libic for arm, linker error when building libic shared target. The error is like below:

```
....
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libic.so
uclient.c:(.text+0xd96): undefined reference to `event_del'
uclient.c:(.text+0xd9e): undefined reference to `event_free'
uclient.c:(.text+0xdae): undefined reference to `event_del'
uclient.c:(.text+0xdb6): undefined reference to `event_free'
uclient.c:(.text+0xdf8): undefined reference to `SSL_get_shutdown'
uclient.c:(.text+0xe0a): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
uclient.c:(.text+0xe5c): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
uclient.c:(.text+0xe90): undefined reference to `event_base_free'
uclient.c:(.text+0xe98): undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
uclient.c:(.text+0xed6): undefined reference to `SSL_get_shutdown'
uclient.c:(.text+0xefa): undefined reference to `SSL_set_shutdown'
uclient.c:(.text+0xf06): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
uclient.c:(.text+0xf12): undefined reference to `SSL_set_shutdown'
uclient.c:(.text+0xf1a): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
```

The configure log is below

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found OpenSSL: /home/drone/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-3.0/mobile/rootstraps/mobile-3.0-device.core/usr/lib/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2k") 
-- Using OpenSSL 1.0.2k
-- Found CURL: /home/drone/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-3.0/mobile/rootstraps/mobile-3.0-device.core/usr/lib/libcurl.so (found version "7.50.2")
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     C++ Compiler:                /home/drone/Downloads/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ (ver 7.3.1)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -std=c++1y -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -std=c++1y -fPIC -g
--     C Compiler:                  /home/drone/Downloads/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -mthumb  -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi -fPIC -g
--   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:          /home/drake/Documents/code/libscs/packages/libscs
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now 
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
```

It seems with cross compile, libic requires to link with openssl. I want to ask that how can I build libic shared without linking with openssl?
Thanks for your support.

Comment: I need more info. Does your library depend directly or indirectly on openSSL? The code of your library has something like `#include <openssl/ssl.h>` ? If the answer is yes to the latter, then it is a direct dependency, so the question is how do you manage to link on the host environment without it?

Comment: Could you provide your CMakeLists.txt please? It would help greatly.

Comment: Maybe your libic library code loads openSSL with [dlopen()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) and unloads it with `dlclose()` ? That means run-time linking instead of build-time. Maybe that is what you want, but in this case the errors would happpen at run-time, when libraries aren't found.

Comment: Thank you guys, I've found the answer, the linker issue occurs because of this linker flag `-Wl,--no-undefined`. Just remove this linker option is OK

Answer (score 0):

If your library depends on libssl, you cannot compile it without linking to libssl. Did you try getting the libssl package for the arm architecture? Off the top of my head, something around the lines of

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm
apt update
apt install libssl-dev:arm
```

Or maybe

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt update
apt install libssl-dev:arm64
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP has already solved to find and install openSSL for his build. Didn't you notice the line `-- Found OpenSSL: /home/drone/tizen-studio/platforms/tizen-3.0/mobile/rootstraps/mobile-3.0-device.core/usr/lib/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2k")` ?

Comment: If the .so was compiled for another architecture, it will not be able to find the symbols. CMake could find libcrypto.so for a non arm architecture, and thus be unable to link. It is hard to say without the CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I've found the answer, the linker issue occurs because of this linker flag -Wl,--no-undefined. Just remove this linker option is OK